# c++ pointer manipulation problem with linked list insert at head for a graph

Tags: c++, pointers, graph, linked-list

I have a Graph class that stores an array of linked list.
I want to insert at head of linked list and set the "next" of the new item to previous head.
However, when I set the new head's "next" as previous head, it ends up setting the new head as its own next causing an infinite loop because the next also points to itself.
Specifically this line in the insert()

```
EdgeNode node = EdgeNode(y, weight, edges[x].isEmpty() ? nullptr : &edges[x]);
```

The **node** object has correct and expected values both for itself and the next.
However, as soon as I assign **node** to the array,

```
    edges[x] = node;//This causes "next" to contain its own reference., causing circular dependency
```

it goes bad and assigns edges[x].getnext() also as edges[x] causing a circular reference.
I even have my own overloaded assignment operator but it did not help.
I think it boils down to simple pointer manipulation. Please explain why it does not work in addition to how to fix it. Dont want to use smart pointers or changing the array of linked list objects to array of pointers.

Here is the the Graph class and main() in the end

```
#include <iostream>

const int MAX_VERTICES = 1000;
class EdgeNode {
    int y{ -1 };
    int weight{ 1 };
    EdgeNode* next{ nullptr };  
public: 
    EdgeNode() : y(-1), weight(1), next(nullptr) {}
    EdgeNode(int _y, int _weight, EdgeNode* _next) : y{ _y }, weight{ _weight }, next(_next) {}
    EdgeNode& operator=(const EdgeNode& other) {
        this->next = other.getNext();
        this->y = other.getY();
        this->weight = other.getWeight();
        return *this;
    }
    int getY() const { return y; } ;
    int getWeight() const { return weight; };
    EdgeNode* getNext() const { return next; };
    bool const isEmpty() { return y == -1; }
};

class Graph {
    EdgeNode edges[MAX_VERTICES];   
public:
    Graph() {};
    void insertEdge(int x, int y, int weight, bool directed) {
        EdgeNode node = EdgeNode(y, weight, edges[x].isEmpty() ? nullptr : &edges[x]);
        edges[x] = node;//This causes "next" to contain its own reference., causing circular dependency
        if (directed) {
            insertEdge(y, x, weight, false);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    Graph graph;    
    graph.insertEdge(1, 11);
    graph.insertEdge(1,  111);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
EdgeNode edges[MAX_VERTICES];
```

You have an array of objects.

When you overwrite an element in the list the object no longer exists, as a result you can not create a chain.

```
    // This creaters a local object.
    // When this function exits this object will no longer exist.
    // Which is fine for the first element in the list (as you copy it).
    // But for the second and third etc this does make a difference  
    EdgeNode node = EdgeNode(y, weight, edges[x].isEmpty() ? nullptr : &edges[x]);


    // Here you copy "node" into `edges`.
    // BUT you are overwritting the current head
    // not adding a new node.
    edges[x] = node;
```

---

To solve this:

```
EdgeNode* edges[MAX_VERTICES];   // an array of pointer.

// ----
EdgeNode*  node = new EdgeNode(y, weight, edges[x].isEmpty() ? nullptr : &edges[x]);
                  ^^^ note the new
edges[x] = node;
```

There are a few issues here. I have not added the code to manage the objects. As with all resource management and making sure you keep this list in sync becomes hard. You can solve this in a couple of ways.

---

Technique 1: Use smart pointer.

```
std::unique_ptr<EdgeNode> edges[MAX_VERTICES];

// ----
std::unique_ptr<EdgeNode>  node = std::make_unique<EdgeNode>(y, weight, edges[x].isEmpty() ? nullptr : &edges[x]);                      
edges[x] = std::move(node);

// Note: Not quite that simple
//       You need to extract objects from the list
//       Which implies the object next should also be a smart pointer
//       which then implies move rather than assign.
```

---

Technique 2: Use a standard container:

```
std::list<EdgeNode> edges[MAX_VERTICES];

// ----
EdgeNode  node = EdgeNode(y, weight); // Let the list handle next/prev for you
edges[x].push_front(node);
```

Comment: Is there a way copy or move the existing elements as "next" in the new head? like a deep copy of &edges[x] ?If something can be done with pointers, it can also be done with regular objects?

Comment: @bsobaid Not in your current design. To use pointers and have an expanding list you need to dynamically allocate the objects.